# Can you call a stored procedure from a trigger in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I want to generate a `BatchID` when a new order is inserted into my database. To achieve this, I have created the following in SQL Server 2022.

Stored procedure `spGenerateBatchID`:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGenerateBatchID]
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @BatchID NVARCHAR(11);
    DECLARE @Chars NVARCHAR(23) = N'34679ACDEFGHJKLMNPQRTXYZ';
    SET @BatchID = 'B';

    WHILE 1 = 1
    BEGIN
        SET @BatchID = 'B';

        -- Generate the first block of 3 alphanumeric characters
        SELECT @BatchID = @BatchID 
            + SUBSTRING(@Chars, CAST(RAND() * LEN(@Chars) + 1 AS INT), 1) 
            + SUBSTRING(@Chars, CAST(RAND() * LEN(@Chars) + 1 AS INT), 1) 
            + '-';

        -- Generate the second block of 3 alphanumeric characters
        SELECT @BatchID = @BatchID 
            + SUBSTRING(@Chars, CAST(RAND() * LEN(@Chars) + 1 AS INT), 1) 
            + SUBSTRING(@Chars, CAST(RAND() * LEN(@Chars) + 1 AS INT), 1) 
            + SUBSTRING(@Chars, CAST(RAND() * LEN(@Chars) + 1 AS INT), 1) 
            + '-';

        -- Generate the third block of 3 alphanumeric characters
        SELECT @BatchID = @BatchID 
            + SUBSTRING(@Chars, CAST(RAND() * LEN(@Chars) + 1 AS INT), 1) 
            + SUBSTRING(@Chars, CAST(RAND() * LEN(@Chars) + 1 AS INT), 1) 
            + SUBSTRING(@Chars, CAST(RAND() * LEN(@Chars) + 1 AS INT), 1);

        -- Check if the generated string already exists in the table
        IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Orders WHERE BatchID = @BatchID)
            BREAK;
    END

    -- Return the generated BatchID
    SELECT @BatchID AS BatchID;
END
GO
```

This works perfectly when I execute: `EXEC dbo.spGenerateBatchID`

Next, I created a trigger to call this stored procedure when a new row is inserted:

Trigger `trgOrdersInsert`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trgOrdersInsert]
ON [dbo].[Orders]
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    PRINT 'trgOrdersInsert fired';

    -- Update the BatchID value for the newly inserted row
    UPDATE Orders
    SET BatchID = dbo.[spGenerateBatchID]()
    FROM Orders
    INNER JOIN inserted ON Orders.Id = inserted.Id;

    -- Print the generated BatchID value
    DECLARE @BatchID NVARCHAR(11);
    SELECT @BatchID = BatchID FROM inserted;

    PRINT 'Generated BatchID: ' + @BatchID;
END;
```

Then to test everything, I run the following script:

```
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE;

DECLARE @InsertedOrders TABLE (Id INT, BatchID NVARCHAR(11), CustomerID INT, OrderDate DATETIME, IsActive BIT);

INSERT INTO Orders (CustomerID, OrderDate, IsActive)
OUTPUT inserted.Id, inserted.BatchID, inserted.CustomerID, inserted.OrderDate, inserted.IsActive INTO @InsertedOrders
VALUES (1, '2023-02-14', 1);

SELECT * FROM @InsertedOrders;
```

But I get the following error:

```
trgOrdersInsert fired
```

> Msg 4121, Level 16, State 1, Procedure trgOrdersInsert, Line 9 [Batch Start Line 0]
> Cannot find either column "dbo" or the user-defined function or aggregate "dbo.spGenerateBatchID", or the name is ambiguous.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

**Additional info**

I have checked that there are no other stored procedures or triggers or anything else in the database with similar names. I have also created everything above again, with a different name, yet I still get the same error. I am running this as `sa` user in SSMS, so I don't think its a permission error.

Comment: `SET BatchID = dbo.[spGenerateBatchID]()` is trying to reference a scalar `FUNCTION`, not a procedure. The syntax for a procedure is `EXEC <Procedure Name>`. Though this smells like an [XY Problem](//xyproblem.info). A trigger should have as minimal impact on the calling transaction, and your procedure has a `WHILE`; which can (will) be terribly slow and therefore have a (large) detrimental effect on the performance of your `INSERT` statements. I would suggest taking a step back and explaining the actual goal here, as I feel that you are very likely taking the wrong path here.

Comment: Stop generating random numbers at runtime - generate a bunch in advance and just pull one off the stack when you need it. [More info here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3055/generating-random-numbers-in-sql-server-without-collisions/?utm_source=AaronBertrand).

Comment: @Larnu - I just need to generate a code for a field when a new record is inserted in the format of BXX-XXX-XXX where X is a non-ambiguous alphanumeric character. I tried to create a Function and set the default or binding value to call the function.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, that is a great idea! Thanks!

Comment: You might not even have to bother pulling one off the stack. You can generate (say) 10 million unique BatchID strings and  sequential `Id` pairings upfront so retrieving the BatchId is just a join onto that table rather than storing it in `Orders`.

Comment: @MartinSmith I like the sound of that! My brain is melting as I have been working on this for hours now. Would you mind expanding on your idea with some pseudo code please?

Comment: No time at the moment. But it was basically just `CREATE TABLE BatchIdMap 
(OrderID INT PRIMARY KEY,BatchID NVARCHAR(11) UNIQUE);` and then fill it in advance with enough values to see you into the forseeable future. You do need to take care that when duplicates are removed from the random generated BatchID there is no sort operation that will lead them correlated with OrderId though

Comment: One way of doing this https://i.stack.imgur.com/mf5Qq.png (generated ids 1 to 9999341 as some were dupes and discarded in my case - could generate more and use `TOP 10000000` to account for that)

Answer (score 0):

With thanks to @AaronBertrand I created a solution, here it is, which will hopefully help others in the future.

I created a BatchIDPool table with 50k pre-generated BatchIDs:

```
-- Create the BatchIDs table with the RowNumber and NextBatchID columns
CREATE TABLE BatchIDPool (
    RowNumber INT PRIMARY KEY,
    NextBatchID NVARCHAR(11)
)

-- Define the list of allowed characters
DECLARE @Chars NVARCHAR(23) = N'34679ACDEFGHJKLMNPQRTXYZ'

-- Generate 5000 unique and random values for the NextBatchID column
;WITH CTE_Numbers AS (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS Number
    FROM sys.columns AS c1 CROSS JOIN sys.columns AS c2
),
CTE_BatchIDs AS (
    SELECT Number,
        'B' 
        + SUBSTRING(@Chars, CAST(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * LEN(@Chars) + 1 AS INT), 1) 
        + SUBSTRING(@Chars, CAST(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * LEN(@Chars) + 1 AS INT), 1) 
        + '-' 
        + SUBSTRING(@Chars, CAST(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * LEN(@Chars) + 1 AS INT), 1) 
        + SUBSTRING(@Chars, CAST(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * LEN(@Chars) + 1 AS INT), 1) 
        + SUBSTRING(@Chars, CAST(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * LEN(@Chars) + 1 AS INT), 1) 
        + '-' 
        + SUBSTRING(@Chars, CAST(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * LEN(@Chars) + 1 AS INT), 1) 
        + SUBSTRING(@Chars, CAST(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * LEN(@Chars) + 1 AS INT), 1) 
        + SUBSTRING(@Chars, CAST(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * LEN(@Chars) + 1 AS INT), 1) AS NextBatchID
    FROM CTE_Numbers
)
INSERT INTO BatchIDPool (RowNumber, NextBatchID)
SELECT Number, NextBatchID
FROM CTE_BatchIDs
WHERE Number <= 50000
```

Then I created a trigger for the Orders table to run on insert:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_Order_BatchID
ON Orders
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @BatchID nvarchar(11);
    DECLARE @Unique bit = 0;
    
    BEGIN TRY
        WHILE @Unique = 0
        BEGIN
            -- Get the top BatchID from BatchIDPool
            SELECT TOP(1) @BatchID = NextBatchID
            FROM BatchIDPool
            ORDER BY RowNumber;

            IF @BatchID IS NULL
            BEGIN
                RAISERROR('No more available BatchIDs in BatchIDPool', 16, 1);
                RETURN;
            END

            -- Check if the selected BatchID is unique
            IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Orders WHERE BatchID = @BatchID)
            BEGIN
                -- Update the inserted rows with the BatchID value
                UPDATE Orders
                SET BatchID = @BatchID
                FROM Orders
                INNER JOIN inserted ON Orders.Id = inserted.Id;

                -- Delete the used BatchID from BatchIDPool
                DELETE FROM BatchIDPool
                WHERE NextBatchID = @BatchID;

                SET @Unique = 1;
            END
            ELSE
            BEGIN
                -- Delete the used BatchID from BatchIDPool
                DELETE FROM BatchIDPool
                WHERE NextBatchID = @BatchID;
            END
        END
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000) = ERROR_MESSAGE();
        DECLARE @ErrorSeverity INT = ERROR_SEVERITY();
        DECLARE @ErrorState INT = ERROR_STATE();

        RAISERROR (@ErrorMessage, @ErrorSeverity, @ErrorState);
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
    END CATCH;
END
```